# how to make a async ajax semi sync to avoid race condition with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

pre1: the explanation of my problem is just an example - not the real situation

pre2: all ajax is asynch

pre3: I don't want to discuss errors / error handling with ajax

Please, imagine I have a simple page with some images of fruits, lets say an apple (of course), an orange and a 42fruit.

When the user clicks one of this images the amount of the fruit is in- or decreased, depending if upper half or lower half of the image.

The "users wish" is sent to the server via ajax, and committed via ajax respond - click by click

To avoid something like a "race", when the user clicks the apple, the apple -image is disabled, until the apple-ajax is finished. (same for others)

so far - no prob.

Now I let the user enter the fruits name in a text box and press '+' or '-' to increase or decrease the amount

If I disable the input until the ajax is ready, all is good, but the user can't enter a new fruit name during this time (or not enter '+/-')

What I would do in other languages is: use a 'named mutex', saying "sorry user - apple update is in progress; choose an other fruit ..."

but how to do that with javascript?   (w/o just looping and blocking)

Answer (score -1):

When you do ajax in javascript you have the option of executing code:

1. During the call
2. Once the call completes
3. Once the call errors out

So what you would want to do is when the call is made, disable the inputs. Once the call is complete you will re-enable the boxes (assuming a successful call). An example is as follows in AngularJS (it is very similar for all other languages):

```
            $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {
            //Disable the button here
            var responsePromise = $http.get("/angularjs-examples/json-test-data.jsp");

            responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //Re-enable the button here
            });
            responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("AJAX failed!");
            });
            }
```

Here is another example in JQuery which will likely be more useful for you:

```
$("button").click(function(){
//Put your code to disable the button here
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    //Put your code to re-enable the button here
}});
});
```

So in the above code you can see that you have the option of calling a given function on success. So you disable the button and then re-enable it once it succeeds.

Comment: you describe my solution for one "button" per fruit, like i said above: "To avoid something like a "race", when the user clicks the apple, the apple -image is disabled, until the apple-ajax is finished. (same for others)"

 -I know how to do that

Comment: I don't understand you question then. You can easily use a solution just like mine and have boolean flags for apple, orange, etc. to see if they are available at the time of processing or not.

Comment: @halfbit If you would still like a solution than you will need to explain further.